# Grouping by column that has most matches

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table with 500K records that contain business id's. Every business record can have anywhere from 0-500 different contacts tied to same business (via business_id).

I am trying to write a query that will find the business record that has the most contacts tied to it.

This is what I tried:

`SELECT * FROM contacts GROUP BY business_id ORDER BY MAX(business_id)`

I appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the count of business_id's and order by the count of business_id's

```
SELECT * ,count(business_id) as cbusiness_id 
FROM contacts 
GROUP BY business_id
ORDER BY cbusiness_id DESC
```

Comment: Should not it be ordered by count(business_id)?

Comment: If its a good question than up vote it! ;) I tried to. SO has a time limit before I can accept the answer.